# what does this 'sweeping round' mean?

Tags: word-meaning

In chapter 3 of Moby-Dick:

> The opposite wall of this entry was hung all over with a heathenish array of monstrous clubs and spears. ... one was sickle-shaped, with a vast handle **sweeping round** like the segments made in the new-mown grass by a long-armed mower.

Does it mean that the handle can be used to sweep the weapon like that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like much of Meville, this is not an easy passage to read due to the ambiguity in punctuation and length.  In his description of The Spouter-Inn, Melville describes several of the implements used in whale craft at the time hung on a wall.

One such implement Melville describes as being

> **sickle-shaped**
>   *having a crescent shaped blade*
>
> **with a vast handle sweeping round**
>   *with a large, extensive handle all around*
>   *sweeping -> extensive*
>   *round -> around*
>
> **like the segments made in the new-mown grass**
>   *like stalk segments in newly cut hay*
>   he compares the general shape to a cut hay stalk with its top curled over
>
> **by a long-armed mower**
>   *by a [scythe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scythe)*

Such an tool would have probably been used to cut the blubber of a whale.

Something like second from the left (below)

[image: description]
<sub>(source: [org.uk](http://www.whitbymuseum.org.uk/collections/images/scor_implements.jpg))</sub>

Answer (score 0):

"Sweeping round" describes the shape of the club's handle. The form of the club is visually sweeping around in a circular fashion, the way hay falls when cut by a mower. But there is no person in the sentence actually performing this action.